# How to inject FirebaseMessagingService in Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service, dagger-2

I want to inject a class into a Service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` but as far as I know, in order to inject stuff in a Service class that service should extends `DaggerService()`.

This is what I tried

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, // Default module, always on top
        AppModule::class,
        ServiceBuilderModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    // Override the builder
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

}


@Module
abstract class ServiceBuilderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeFirebaseCloudMessaging(): CloudMessaging

}
```

The service class

```
class CloudMessaging : FirebaseMessagingService() {


    @Inject
    lateinit var parser: JsonParser

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)


        val msgData = parser.fromJsonString<CommonNotification>(remoteMessage.data.toString(), CommonNotification::class.java)
            ?: return

    }

}
```

But the above code is not working as I am getting

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property parser has not been initialized
```

Comment: You've marked `parser` with `@Inject`, I don't see any provider for `JsonParser`.

Comment: @DarShan I did not include it since that is working perfectly in other class except when using it inside a `FirebaseMessagingService`. So I need you to trust me on that part :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! All you need to do is call `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` inside `onCreate` and before its call to super. This will manually inject the FCM Service class since we can't make it extend `DaggerService` which supposed to do that job for us.